# Writing full record to .csv file from For Loop Python csvreader

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to write the entire row of a .csv file that has been found modified via a For, In loop. I have managed to get the program to write the keys to a csv file but I can't get it to write the associated values along with those keys. I'm unsure if I need another loop nested in or if I am just making a mistake with the syntax.

```
import csv

def make_billing_dict(csv_dict_reader):
    bdict = {}
    for entry in csv_dict_reader:
    key = entry['BillingNumber']
    bdict[key] = entry
    return bdict

with open('old/MTBT.txt') as csv_file:
    old = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    old_bills = make_billing_dict(old)

with open('new/MTBT.txt') as csv_file:
    new = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    new_bills = make_billing_dict(new)

diff = file("diff/diff.csv", "wb" )
writer = csv.writer(diff)

for keys in old_bills:
    if old_bills[keys]['CustomerName'] != new_bills[keys]['CustomerName'] or old_bills[keys]['IsActive'] != new_bills[keys]['IsActive'] or old_bills[keys]['IsPayScan'] != new_bills[keys]['IsPayScan']:
        writer.writerow([keys])



#Used to send records to the console
#       print (new_bills[keys]['BillingNumber'],new_bills[keys]['CustomerName'],new_bills[keys]['IsActive'],new_bills[keys]['IsPayScan'],new_bills[keys]['IsCreditHold'],new_bills[keys]['City'],new_bills[keys]['State'])

#print set(new_bills.keys()) - set(old_bills.keys())
```

Also, I have noticed that if I add a new key and entry into the new file it causes no problems but if I remove a record it causes a key error. I understand why, because it's looking for a key that's in the original dict but is there any way around this issue?

Comment: Did you mean to write `old_bills[keys]` instead perhaps?

Comment: Well I keep trying different things, but I haven't gotten it right yet. That gives me a strange result of the CustomerName separated by all commas such as A,n,d,r,e,w, I have tried other things such as writer.writerow([keys,"CustomerName"]) but that gives the key followed by "CustomerName" not the actual value

Comment: Ah, you are using a `csv.writer()` which wants a sequence instead. Your `old_bills` mapping contains dictionaries instead, so you need to either use `csv.DictWriter()` or turn your dicts into lists (`.values()` would do that, but in arbitrary order).

Comment: When I try using csv.DictWriter is gives me the error that it takes 3 arguments and I've only given 2. I have tried numerous attempts with that as well, I feel like i'm missing something really minute

Comment: When you encounter an error like that, you look up the documentation. [`csv.DictWriter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) needs a sequence of field names.

Comment: I did look it up, but even after various changes it gives the error that I need an integer, but I don't understand why.